# Assign all epics with their children to me in Azure Boards

Tags: azure-devops, devops, scrum, azure-boards

I have a project in Azure DevOps where there are multiple epics, each with features and tasks. Is there a way to assign the epic with all its features and tasks to me without having to go to each feature and to each task inside and assign them to me one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do these things easily through the queries tab:

- Make it a Tree of work items:
  [image]
- Set the top level work item type to `Epic` and the relationship to `parent/child`:
  [image]
- Save the query:
  [image]
- Switch to the results tab. Hit <kbd>ctrl-a</kbd> to select all the results. Use the <kbd>...</kbd> and pick <kbd>Assign to ></kbd>:
  [image]
- Hit <kbd>Save Items...</kbd>.

And as it turns out, you can do the same from the Backlogs tab. Make sure you select the `Epics` level, <kbd>ctrl-a</kbd> and basically follow the same steps (but you have to expand all the levels manually it seems):

[image]